# Healenium SelfHealingDriver issue

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, healenium

Healenium is implemented along with selenium into our java project. After selfhealingdriver initialization is completed, driver is showing as null.

Hi Team,

I tried selfhealingdriver in the place of remote webdriver. Driver should be work but it is showing as null

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.